# c++ 3D matrix using vector poor performance

Tags: c++, matlab, opencv, matrix

hello all I was trying to convert this matlab code into c++.
BTW can also use openCV.

```
 imageData = toolbox.bayer.ColorOrder.cat( imageData, 0, 3);
```

this is imageData before

```
1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10
11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20
21  22  23  24  25  26  27  28  29  30
31  32  33  34  35  36  37  38  39  40
```

this is image data after:

val(:,:,1) =

```
 1     3     5     7     9
21    23    25    27    29
```

val(:,:,2) =

```
 2     4     6     8    10
22    24    26    28    30
```

val(:,:,3) =

```
11    13    15    17    19
31    33    35    37    39
```

val(:,:,4) =

```
12    14    16    18    20
32    34    36    38    40
```

here is my c++ code I'm getting int** can't change that...

```
vector<vector<vector<double> > > Utilities::MatrixConcat(int **raw_frame, int _width, int _height)
{
    vector<vector<vector<double> > > imageData;
    imageData.resize(_height/2);
    for (int i = 0; i < _height/2; ++i) 
    {
        imageData[i].resize(_width/2);

        for (int j = 0; j < _width/2; ++j)
        {
            imageData[i][j].resize(4);
        }
    }
    //[x][y][0]
    for (int h = 0; h < _height/2; h++)
    {       
        for (int w = 0; w < _width/2; w++)
        {           
            imageData[h][w][0] = raw_frame[2*h][2*w];           
        }
    }
    //[x][y][1]
    for (int h = 0; h < _height/2; h++)
    {       
        for (int w = 0; w < _width/2; w++)
        {           
            imageData[h][w][1] = raw_frame[2*h][2*w+1];
        }
    }

    for (int h = 0; h < _height/2; h++)
    {       
        for (int w = 0; w < _width/2; w++)
        {           
            imageData[h][w][2] = raw_frame[2*h+1][2*w];
        }
    }

    for (int h = 0; h < _height/2; h++)
    {       
        for (int w = 0; w < _width/2; w++)
        {           
            imageData[h][w][3] = raw_frame[2*h+1][2*w+1];
        }
    }
return imageData;
}
```

My problem is that my matrix (not the one for testing) is 4000X3000 which means this function takes too long. can you explain what is taking so long and how can I optimize this?

I can use openCV as well to convert this 2D matrix into a 3D matrix.

Update:

here is the test i have built for getting the same result

```
int** gili = new int*[4];
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        gili[i] = new int[10];
    } 

    for (int i = 0,k=1; i < 4; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
        {
            gili[i][j] = k;
            k++;
        }
    }
    vector<vector<vector<double> > > imageData = Utilities::MatrixConcat(gili,10,4);
```

Comment: I think vector of vector of vector isn't a good fit for this kind of problem.  Multidimensional arrays like this perform terribly for various reasons, including cache locality.  I would have just one vector large enough for all of the data and pass pointers or indicies around instead.

Comment: @Robinson but I need to create a 3 matrix. and later on access element in place arr[x][y][z] .... how can one vector help me with this?

Comment: to people who reduce points please explain why ?

Comment: @Gilad, try using a 1-D array (or better `std::vector`), then overload `operator[]` (or better, just make a member function) to return `(x,y,z)` component via 3-D indexing, like `arr[x][y][z]` gets the element `arr[x*NUM_DIMS + y*NUM_COLS + z*NUM_ROWS]` (may be wrong here but you get the idea, you map a 1-D array to a 3-D one and viceversa). And don't worry for downvoters, it's part of the game :)

Comment: Do you really need `arr[x][y][z]` or would `arr(x,y,z)` suffice?

Comment: @MikeMB as i said I need to transform matlab code to c++ so as long as I can set and get any element I'm fine with () {} or []

Comment: The formula would be x + (y * width) + (z * width * height) - I think, or similar.  There are various ways to optimise that if it's still not fast enough, by organising a row for each z in a contiguous block of memory for example, etc.

Comment: @Robinson yes of course, it's basically like transforming an integer into a multi-index (or variable base if you want), upvoted the comment :)

Comment: so maybe i'll just hold 4 different vectors with the 4  2D arrays?

Comment: @Gilad, doesn't make sense. Just hold one single vector, then learn how to translate from `n` (in you case 3) dimensions into one, and viceversa. Holding only one vector guarantees contiguous storage, and this is important if you want speed (less cache misses etc)

Comment: The important thing is keep the cache full.  That means as your X increases (your inner loop), you want your memory access to be contiguous, not jumping all over the place.  You may have to reorganise it to get the kind of performance you want, e.g. depending on how the input is organised (row or column major).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two problems with your code, the data structure and the access order.

**Data structure**
A vector of vectors of vectors is probably not the most efficient data structure, because each access via the index operators involves some degree of pointer chasing. This could be somewhat mitigated by using iterators (where possible) or you build a wrapper around a single vector/array that allows you to translate a three dimensional position into an index for that container.

A simple 3D matrix implementation could look like this:

```
class Matrix3D{
private:
    size_t sizeX, sizeY, sizeZ;
    std::vector<double> data;
    size_t getIdx(size_t x, size_t y, size_t z) const {
        return x + sizeX*y + sizeX*sizeY*z;
    }

public:
    Matrix3D(size_t X, size_t Y, size_t Z) :sizeX(X), sizeY(Y), sizeZ(Z),data(X*Y*Z){}
    double& operator()(size_t x, size_t y, size_t z){ return data[getIdx(x, y, z)]; }
    double operator() (size_t x, size_t y, size_t z) const{ return data[getIdx(x, y, z)]; }

    //arithmetic operators
};
```

Or if the dimensions are a compile time constant:

```
    template<size_t sizeX, size_t sizeY, size_t sizeZ>
class Matrix3D_ConstDim{
private:    
    std::unique_ptr<std::array<double,sizeX*sizeY*sizeZ>> data;
    size_t getIdx(size_t x, size_t y, size_t z) const {
        return x + sizeX*y + sizeX*sizeY*z;
    }
public:
    Matrix3D_ConstDim(){
        data = std::make_unique<std::array<double, sizeX*sizeY*sizeZ>>();
    }
    double& operator()(size_t x, size_t y, size_t z){ return (*data)[getIdx(x, y, z)]; }
    double operator() (size_t x, size_t y, size_t z) const{ return (*data)[getIdx(x, y, z)]; }
    //arithmetic operators
};
```

Usage :

```
int main() {
    Matrix3D m1(10, 5, 4);
    m1(1, 2, 3) = 4.5;
    std::cout << m1(1, 2, 3) << std::endl;

    Matrix3D_ConstDim<10, 5, 4> m2;
    m2(1, 2, 3) = 4.5;
    std::cout << m2(1, 2, 3) << std::endl;
}
```

**Element access**
The second (and probably more important) thing is sequential access. If you want to iterate over all elements in your matrix, make sure that you access the elements in the same order as they are layed out in memory. As a result, almost all accesses will result in a cache hit (even when the first element in a cache line is accessed, you'll have - thanks to prefetching - a high chance for a l1 cache hit. It might also allow your compiler to perform auto-vertorization of your code. That means the compiler will use special instructions, to perform multiple iterations of the loop at the same time.
If you e.g wanted to initialize above matrixes the code could look like this:

```
    for (size_t z = 0; z < 4; ++z){
        for (size_t y = 0; y < 4; ++y){
            for (size_t x = 0; x < 4; ++x){ //<-- inner most loop changes X
                m1(x, y, z) = x*(y + 1)*(z + 2); //<-- arbitrary values
            }
        }
    }
```